# Logging SD transactions on RPi 3B+

Tags: raspbian

**Problem**: how to make RPi log every SD transaction, with timestamp?
**Or, even better:** how to make it count how often is full-duplex mode really used?

**Background**: I am designing an SPI-based SD card driver. Now I'm using SPI full-duplex mode and 2 DMA channels for both the transmitter and the receiver. I wonder whether this actually makes a lot of sense in a general case - if half-duplex is enough, I will save one DMA channel. I couldn't find any information about usage of full-duplex mode in communication with an SD card, thus I want to check on my Raspberry Pi (3B+, I use it as a normal computer on daily basis) how often is data simultanously read from and written to the SD card.

Comment: Welcome @eerio! Could you please clarify: do you want to log into a file a message with a time stamp each time you read and write to your RPi's SD card? The one that stores your boot and filesystem partitions? Or do you want to monitor read and write operations made on another, external SD card?

Comment: Yes, it's prefered to log transactions with the RPi's SD card, because it's used extensively under normal usage of Raspberry Pi.